# javascript get class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assume there are three classes

```
<div class="hello world_1"></div>
<div class="hello world_2"></div>
<div class="hello world_3"></div>
```

I want to get the class name "world_1","world_2" and "world_3" based on "hello". The code:

```
$('.hello').each(function(){
  this.attr('class');
});
```

got error saying:

```
TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'attr'
```

I experimented a little bit and found

```
$('.hello:first').attr('class')
```

works while

```
$('.hello')[0].attr('class')
```

raises the above error.

Could anyone explain why it happened and how can I get what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wrap the `this`, like so...

```
$('.hello').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('class');
});
```

jQuery provides `this` as a reference to a native DOM element. To able to call jQuery methods on it, wrap it with the jQuery constructor.

If you want to match class of pattern `world_n`, you could use...

```
var matches = $(this).attr('class').match(/(?:^|\s)world_\d+(?:\s|$)/);
```

Comment: @alex Can you elaborate, why `/(?:^|\s)world_\d+(?:^|\$)/` ([which doesn't work at all](http://jsfiddle.net/J22Ex/) ) and not simple `/world_\d+/` ?

Comment: @Engineer That's a massive fail on my behalf. I'll fix it.

Comment: @alex I just want to know, why do you need that "complicated stuff" ?

Comment: @Engineer It depends. You may have another class with `world_` in it that you don't want to match.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('.hello').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('class');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whats happening is that the jquery `each` function sets the `this` to be the DOM element, and doesn't 'prewrap' the jquery wrapper around this element.

So like alex has said, simply wrapping it again will give you want you want.

Answer (score 0):

To get only the `world_`class names, you'll need to do a string replace and remove whitespaces using $.trim:

```
$('.hello').each(function(){
  $.trim($(this).attr('class').replace('hello', ''));
});
```